# Filtering by datetime confusion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a datetime object that is not the index and when I filter it by:

```
 df=df[(df['local_time']>=datetime.date(2015,2,18))]
 df=df.sort_values('local_time',ascending=[True])
```

why does df.head(1) show 2-17-2015 as the first date when im using: >=datetime.date(2015,2,18)

Comment: Your error can not be reproduced , please add your sample data

Comment: Ugg..I think i figured it out..datatype is datetime64[ns, UTC] Universal time, and it must be using local time for the conversion.

Comment: Sorry, the clickable "check mark" wasnt very intuitive to me..Now i know!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured out a fix.

Not sure exactly why it works, but when I pass it to a pd.Series
it works...--- both return a datetime64[ns, UTC] type, and although they look similiar they behave differently...still strange:

fix:

```
 df['local_time']=pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df.ts),utc=True)
```